# Cannot ping from on-prem machine to an azure vnet

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-vpn, vnet

I cannot ping from an on-premises VM to a VM in Azure via the VPN gateway connection. The problem occurs only if the VM in Azure is in a VNET that is not the same with the VNET the VPN connection is established. However there is a peering connection between the Azure VNETs. Is this a feature or a miss-configuration from my side?

So here is the setup:

- VNET0: VNET on prem in the space 192.168.90.0/24
- VM0: VM on prem in the VNET0 (IP 192.168.90.4)
- VNET1: VNET in Azure in the space 10.15.0.0/16
- VNET2: VNET in Azure in the space 10.16.0.0/16
- VNET peering in Azure between VNET1 and VNET2 allowing traffic forwarding
- VPN gateway from on-prem VNET0 to Azure VNET1
- VM1 in Azure connected in the VNET1 and in more details in the subnet 10.15.90.0/24 (IP 10.15.90.4)
- VM2 in Azure connected in the VNET2 and in more details in the subnet 10.16.90.0/24 (IP 10.16.90.4)
- Network security group in Azure allowing all traffic from anywhere to anywhere assigned in the VNET2 and in more detail in the subnet 10.16.90.0/24
- The configuration on the on-premises firewall VPN tunnel has a rule allowing incoming and outgoing traffic in the on-premises firewall from both VNET1 and VNET2

Problem

- Working scenario: can ping from the VM0 the VM1
- Non-working scenario: cannot ping from VM0 the VM2

Any idea where the problem could be?

Comment: Hi, you need to create two VNet peerings, if you have any question, please let me know.

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong. I already have 2 VNET peerings. I followed the guide that you showed me but it does not seem to work. 

There is no VPN client to re download since the VPN is configured in our Fortigate Firewall. I brought the IPsec tunnel up and down after configuring the VNET peering but no chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the **Allow gateway transit** option in the "Hub-RM" virtual network in a peering from Azure VNET1 to Azure VNET2 and enable the **Use remote gateways** in the "Spoke-RM" virtual network in a peering from Azure VNET2 to Azure VNET1. Do not select **allow traffic forwarding**.

Note: If you have a P2S VPN connection, once you change the peering setting, you should redownload the VPN client from Azure VPN gateway portal and reinstall it on the on-premise machine to make the route update on your on-premise network.

Get more details from [configuring VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-network%2Ftoc.json)

### Update

After confirming with you, you actually want to do the s2s connection with Azure VPN gateway with VNet Peering following the [article](https://cookbook.fortinet.com/ipsec-vpn-microsoft-azure-54/). I suggest that you have VNet peering configuring with gateway transit between VNet1 and VNet2. You have to make sure the on-premise VNet has the routing for VNet2 and VNet1. After you have a static route configured correctly in the Fortigate(on-premise firewall). This works.

Comment: Still somethign is wrong. I followed the guide but I still face the same issue.
Unfortunately no matter what I do the gateway of the VM2 which is connected to the VNET2  is still 10.16.90.1 while I would expect it to be 10.15.90.1 like for the VM1 which is connected to the VNET1 since I am configured the peerings on one side to Allow gateway transit and on the other side to Use remote gateways.

Comment: What do you mean "It seems that you do not use Azure VPN gateway"? The VPN gateway is deployed an the connection with on-prem infrastructure and the VM1 in Azure is working.

Comment: Could you set an S2S connection with Azure VNet according to this [article](https://cookbook.fortinet.com/ipsec-vpn-microsoft-azure-54/)? It has an Azure virtual network gateway and Local virtual network gateway on the Azure portal.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. In step 6 I created 2 firewall objects and added them both in step 7. One object for each VNETs address space. In step 8 I added one static route for each VNET.

Comment: Technically you have enabled the VPN gateway transit, VNet2 should have a valid VPN gateway. You could check both peering VNets status is connected and the [effective routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-routing-problem#diagnose-using-azure-portal) VM2. Also, VNet1 and VNet2 should locate at the same region.

Comment: Also, you could create a [user-defined route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#custom-routes) in VNet2 for on-premise VNet0 if you have not enabled [BGP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-bgp-overview) in VPN gateway and peering.

Comment: @aragorn Could you verify VNet peering is working? and Could you ping from VM2 to Vm1 and VM0?

Comment: The problem was the static route that was not configured correctly in the Fortunate. Once done everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The static route of the VNET2 in the Fortigate firewall was not configured. Configuring it solved the problem.

Comment: So you just configure a Static route? but actually, you do the gateway transit from my reply? I also confused that you said before `In step 8 I added one static route for each VNET`. From your comment, I think you have added the static route for each VNet like VNet1 and VNet2. So the root cause will be gateway transit in my reply according to your original question, you should accept or upvote my reply for someone references

Comment: Yes you are right. I upvoted your answer and marked it as the correct answer after you edited it. Thank you for your help.